# Узнать юзабельность процедур в БД

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Допустим, есть БД и в этой бд много древних процедур.

Хотелось бы удалить все лишнее.

Так вот, можно ли где-нибудь получить статистику об использовании процедур?

Например, зная, что процедура не используется, ее можно будет грохнуть

Comment: А если процедура используется в приложении

Comment: Ну, если она используется, то статистика это покажет. Если такое имеется в MS SQL.

Comment: Как она это покажет? Максимум Вы можете увидеть какие процедуры вызывались за время мониторинга. Но если процедура не была вызвана за это время, это не значит, что она не используется

Comment: Вдруг у вас есть процедура которая удаляет какие нибудь архивные данные и вызывается один раз в год...